# Переносимость приложения

Tags: windows, c++

Возникла небольшая проблема. Написал на языке C++ в Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 программу в обычном консольном приложении CLR. Далее в папке с проектом нашёл сам исполняемый файл программы и запускал. Но сам исполняемый файл работает на любых компьютерах, с любой разрядностью системы, но только с установленным С, а без него выдаёт ошибку, связанную с неправильной параллельной конфигурацией. Не знаю, как по-другому компилировать.

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы исполняемый файл моей программы работал на любом компьютере, без среды программирования.

Comment: Точный текст ошибки приведите.

Answer (score 2):

Хрустальный шар без текста ошибки предполагает, что дело в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable с крайне высокой вероятностью ))

- [vcredist_x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe)
- [vcredist_x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/2/3224B87F-CFA0-4E70-BDA3-3DE650EFEBA5/vcredist_x64.exe)

Ну, это вам вряд ли нужно будет: [vcredist_IA64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/3/A/33A75193-2CBC-424E-A886-287551FF1EB5/vcredist_IA64.exe).

Это набор системных библиотек, которые юзает ваша программа.

Эту хрень нужно будет устанавливать на ПК, где будете запускать свою программу.
Или включайне в дистрибутив.

Comment: Еще можно собрать статический .exe, но в VS я не знаю как.
С gcc просто gcc -static ....

Кстати, с gcc и консольными программами у меня никогда таких проблем не возникало. Даже -static не нужен. Все на стандартных виндовых .dll

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, надо устанавливать [MS Visual Studio Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?familyid=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84)